# Sliding any JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, slide

Im trying to make a universal class for sliding two any-samesized JPanels but when I use it, the one to get slid just disappears. What I also noticed is that the JPanel "innerPanel"'s width is being reset (when transisting a 200,200 panel) from 400,200 that the size gets reset to 200,200 after the Thread is started

```
package org.chimeras1684.ui.panels;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JViewport;

/**
 *
 * @author Arhowk
 */
public final class Transistor extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form test
 */
public enum TDirection{
    MOVING_TO_LEFT,
    MOVING_TO_RIGHT,
    MOVING_TO_TOP,
    MOVING_TO_BOTTOM;
}
private static Transistor instance;
static{
    instance = new Transistor();
}
public static Transistor getInstance(){
    return instance;
}
private Transistor() {
    initComponents();
    setVisible(true);
    slide(TDirection.MOVING_TO_TOP, this, jPanel2, jPanel1);
}

public void slide(final TDirection dir, final JFrame root, final JPanel in, final JPanel out){
    if(in.getSize().height != out.getSize().height ||  out.getSize().width != in.getSize().width ){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Dimension in is not equal to dimension of out");
    }
    panelTL.removeAll();
    panelBL.removeAll();
    panelBR.removeAll();
    panelTR.validate();
    panelTR.repaint();
    panelTL.validate();
    panelTL.repaint();
    panelBR.validate();
    panelBR.repaint();
    panelBL.validate();
    panelBL.repaint();
    final double width = in.getSize().width;
    final double height = in.getSize().height;

    int x = out.getLocation().x;
    int y = out.getLocation().y;

    final double speedWidthModifier = (dir == TDirection.MOVING_TO_LEFT) ? -1 : (dir == TDirection.MOVING_TO_RIGHT) ? 1 : 0;
    final double speedHeightModifier = (dir == TDirection.MOVING_TO_BOTTOM) ? -1 : (dir == TDirection.MOVING_TO_TOP) ? 1 : 0;

    final double xAtEnd = (dir == TDirection.MOVING_TO_RIGHT) ? width : 0;
    final double yAtEnd = (dir == TDirection.MOVING_TO_BOTTOM) ? height : 0;

    if(dir == TDirection.MOVING_TO_LEFT){
        panelTR.setSize(200,200);
        panelTL.setSize(200,200);
        panelTL.add(in);
        panelTR.add(out);
    }
    if(dir == TDirection.MOVING_TO_RIGHT){
        panelTR.setSize(200,200);
        panelTL.setSize(200,200);
        panelTL.add(out);
        panelTR.add(in);
    }
    if(dir == TDirection.MOVING_TO_BOTTOM){
        panelBL.setSize(200,200);
        panelTL.setSize(200,200);
        panelBL.add(in);
        panelTL.add(out);
    }
    if(dir == TDirection.MOVING_TO_TOP){
        panelBL.setSize(200,200);
        panelTL.setSize(200,200);
        panelBL.add(out);
        panelTL.add(in);
    }
    root.remove(out);
    scrollPanel.setSize(in.getSize());
    innerPanel.setSize(in.getSize().width * 2, in.getSize().height);
    root.add(scrollPanel);
    scrollPanel.setLocation(x, y);
    if(speedWidthModifier == 0 && speedHeightModifier == 0){
        throw new NullPointerException("TDirection dir");
    }
    System.out.println(new Date());
            System.out.println("tlsize1: " + panelTL.getSize());

    (new Timer()).schedule(new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("tlsize1: " + panelTL.getSize());
    System.out.println(new Date());

            Point viewport = scrollPanel.getViewport().getViewPosition();
            JViewport newViewport = scrollPanel.getViewport();

            double currentX = viewport.x;
            double currentY = viewport.y;   

            double speed = 50;

            double newX = currentX + (speed * speedWidthModifier);
            double newY = currentY + (speed * speedHeightModifier);

            newViewport.getViewPosition().x = (int)newX;
            newViewport.getViewPosition().y = (int)newY;

            if((xAtEnd != 0 && newX > xAtEnd) || (yAtEnd != 0 && newY > yAtEnd)){
                this.cancel();
            }

            root.repaint();
            System.out.println("tlsize2: " + panelTL.getSize());
        }

    }, 0,25);
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {
    java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

    scrollPanel = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    innerPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    panelTL = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    panelTR = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    panelBL = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    panelBR = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    scrollPanel.setBorder(null);
    scrollPanel.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    scrollPanel.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

    innerPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 153));
    innerPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

    panelTL.setAutoscrolls(true);
    panelTL.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout panelTLLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panelTL);
    panelTL.setLayout(panelTLLayout);
    panelTLLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        panelTLLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    panelTLLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        panelTLLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
    innerPanel.add(panelTL, gridBagConstraints);

    panelTR.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout panelTRLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panelTR);
    panelTR.setLayout(panelTRLayout);
    panelTRLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        panelTRLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    panelTRLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        panelTRLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
    innerPanel.add(panelTR, gridBagConstraints);

    panelBL.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout panelBLLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panelBL);
    panelBL.setLayout(panelBLLayout);
    panelBLLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        panelBLLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    panelBLLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        panelBLLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
    innerPanel.add(panelBL, gridBagConstraints);

    panelBR.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 0, 51));
    panelBR.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout panelBRLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panelBR);
    panelBR.setLayout(panelBRLayout);
    panelBRLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        panelBRLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    panelBRLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        panelBRLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
    innerPanel.add(panelBR, gridBagConstraints);

    scrollPanel.setViewportView(innerPanel);

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 153, 0));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 200, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 200, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 0));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 200, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 200, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(scrollPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(109, 109, 109)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 90, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(78, 78, 78))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(scrollPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(35, 35, 35))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Transistor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Transistor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Transistor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Transistor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Transistor().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JPanel innerPanel;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel panelBL;
private javax.swing.JPanel panelBR;
private javax.swing.JPanel panelTL;
private javax.swing.JPanel panelTR;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane scrollPanel;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Yes, I know the class extends JFrame, I'm just using that for testing purposes. (I'm also not sure how to fix the indenting on this page)

Answer (score 2):

Components in Swing are generally under the control of a layout manager.  To achieve what you are trying to do, you would actually be better of creating an animated layout manager.

I suggest you take a look at...

- [The Universal Tween Engine](http://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/)
- [Sliding layout](https://github.com/AurelienRibon/sliding-layout)

You could also take a look at [Animations when using Gridbag Layout.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540080/animations-when-using-gridbag-layout/14541651#14541651) (shameless plug)

Comment: This is really only for one project so I dont see the need to create a new layout manager... Also, I've ttried to work with sliding layout but the API is really hard to follow. Also, theyre under the control of a GridBag layout

Comment: The problem your facing is, your components are under the control of a layout manager. So any attempt to modify the components size of position will be counted by the layout manager.  The last example uses a proxy layout manager and provide the animation layer, so it should (in theory) work with other layout managers

Comment: I dont think it has to do with the layout manager, its still giving me the same issue with a null layout (sizes and locations are getting reset every repaint)

Comment: If you're not using a layout manager, then you won't need validate, invalidate or revalidate as the deal primarily with layouts.  You should be using javax.swing.Timer instead of java.util.Timer as it honors the restrictions of the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: I had been using a GridBagLayout previously but I changed it to null. The X/Y position of the viewport is still getting reest after every timer iteration