# I am using Card layout in java swing application and want to perform some nice effect on card change from one to another

Tags: java, swing, awt

In a java Swing application and if we are using Card layout for some panel than we use to show() method to show particular card.Show Method just make visible given card and disappear current card.
Is it Possible to add some effects between this card swapping?

**effects like**:-

1. List item
2. Left to rightte moving.
3. Top to Bottom.
4. Fade in and Fade out effect.
5. Zooming Effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with card layout.

You could take a look at the [SlidingLayout](https://github.com/AurelienRibon/sliding-layout), which is based on [The Universal Tween Engine](https://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/)

Another approach is to design a layout manager capable of providing the required functionality.  This is far more complex, but gives you an idea of what might be involved...

For example, [Animations when using Gridbag Layout.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540080/animations-when-using-gridbag-layout/14541651#14541651)

Comment: See also these lower-level [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16316132/230513).