# How to make a Jpanel slide?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, animated

I want to make a jpanel slide up and a down in a button action (Eg: Android quick settings panel style), I tried using JXTaskPane, but it's cannot be customized as i want it to be. Can anyone help me do that?

Comment: Take a look at [Universal Tween Engine](https://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/) and [SlidingLayout](https://github.com/AurelienRibon/sliding-layout)

Comment: Or, if you want to do some work, you could do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540080/animations-when-using-gridbag-layout/14541651#14541651) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368190/too-many-jpanels-inside-a-jpanel-with-gridbaglayout/32372506#32372506) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463989/java-moving-jlabel-twice-using-timer/27466801#27466801) (which are all based on the same idea)

Comment: Thanks bro, started using it, Lets see how its going :)

Comment: Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16316132/230513).