# Animating hidemode in miglayout

Tags: java, swing

I have to make google image view in java.

I think I can make image list with miglayout hidemode 3: todo hide and show detail which is shown when the image is clicked.
But I need to animate when the detail is hidden and is appeared.
Any idea and better suggestions are really appreciated

Comment: *"Any idea*" - Plenty, but you're probably not going to like the answer.  You could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540080/animations-when-using-gridbag-layout/14541651#14541651) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463989/java-moving-jlabel-twice-using-timer/27466801#27466801) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368190/too-many-jpanels-inside-a-jpanel-with-gridbaglayout/32372506#32372506) which basically creates a "proxy" animated layout wrapper.

Comment: You could also consider using something like [universal-tween-engine](https://github.com/AurelienRibon/universal-tween-engine)

Comment: I'd also suggest having a look at something like the [timing framework](https://github.com/akuhtz/timingframework) which provides a basic animation engine - much easier then trying to role your own - has nice features like built in easement